# Can a web page be refreshed continuously for approx 2 hours using load runner?

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, refresh, loadrunner

how can I refresh a webpage continuously using load runner ?

I am looking for an option with loadrunner and not selenium , js or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Define, "refresh continuously."

Why do I ask this?  The server does not care what is on the other end of the request.  It could be a full client.  It could be a test tool like LoadRunner.  It could be a program written in Python.   It could be a command line tool like cUrl.  The server has no concept of "refresh" on the client, only responding to a request.

You could put a single page load in a loop with no thinktime between requests.  This would violate a core tenet of client-server computing, that a delay exists between requests from a client during which the items returned are being processed by either the silicon or organic computing units on the client front.

```
lr_start_transaction("foo");
while (lr_get_transaction_duration("foo")<3600)
{
// my request code here
sleep(rand()%9000 + 1001);
}
lr_stop_transaction("foo");
```

On reporting systems one often observes behavior of polling to see when a report is complete.   The delay between these requests is often 5-10 seconds for a refresh of the report request.   This is typically handled in LoadRunner code with a looping structure which breaks when the report is actually returned.  Inside of the loop it issues the request, checks the result to see if exit is warranted, waits the 5-10 seconds then loops.

You could have a script with one request, loaded in the controller with either zero or some pacing.  Schedule it for an hour of execution.

many many ways

Comment: The aim is to just keep refreshing/reloading a webpage. So basically a refresh page transaction would do the needful here ?

Comment: Record with vugen.  Load the page.  Start a transaction or remark. Hit the f5 key to refresh. Insert end transction or another remark.   The calls between your two transaction markers or remarks shows what a "refresh" looks like from a server perspective.   The server has no concept of items that occur in the DOM to actually refresh a page to the user, on the concept of a request/response pairing.